# FastAPI File(s) must be put before form in function parameters

Tags: python-3.6, fastapi, pydantic

I have an endpoint that takes a file and a string parameter that I pass through a form body. But I noticed when debugging that:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, Form

app = FastAPI()


@app.post('/test')
def test(test_item: str = Form(...), test_file: bytes = File(...)):
    return {
        "test_item": test_item,
        "test_file_len": len(test_file),
        "test_file_contents": test_file.decode('utf-8')
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

using this simple curl command with the test_file.txt having some text in it:

```
curl localhost:8000/test -X POST -F test_file=@"test_file.txt" -F test_item="test"
```

didn't work with this error:

```
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body",
                "test_file"
            ],
            "msg": "byte type expected",
            "type": "type_error.bytes"
        }
    ]
}
```

but interestingly, this did work:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, Form

app = FastAPI()


@app.post('/test')
def test(test_file: bytes = File(...), test_item: str = Form(...)):
    return {
        "test_item": test_item,
        "test_file_len": len(test_file),
        "test_file_contents": test_file.decode('utf-8')
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

the only difference being that you get the File before the Form element. Does anybody know why that would happen? Looks like it's required to upload files before forms. Maybe the file gets killed when Form parses the http form body. I didn't see anything on the FastAPI documentation about this for Form and Files.

Answer (score 1):

This was working in FastApi 0.43.0.

This is a regression introduced in https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/commit/ab2b86fe2ce8fe15e91aaec179438e24ff7b7ed0

Comment: I've submitted an issue : https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1964

Comment: I've submitted a pull request : https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/11194 (I know, it's been 3 years)